# How does the deployment from Azure DevOps to multiple App Service Plan instances work?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-service-plans

I have an app service plan with three instances and an app service with two deployment slots running on it. I deploy with Azure DevOps to the first deployment slot and run some integration tests in the deployment script against this slot; if they are fine I switch this slot in the script to production.

Now my question is when and how are the other instances of the app service plan updated?

I know it's done automatically, but its all a bit magical there and I could not find any proper documentation on this. Even Kudu into these different instances is not that easy, sow how's this Azure managing and handling this?

Comment: These instances are running on a single or group of VM's that I think share the same code base that you deploy which means it should be almost instant for the clones to get the new modification. I don't think MSFT will go deeper than what they already have regarding such topics because we are getting a black box (almost) when we use the app service model.